# how to implement custom ArrayList based on ArrayList.util without ability to delete elements

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to implement ArrayList which is would not allow to user (or program) to delete elements from it. I want to keep rest of functionality of ArrayList.
The question is what is the better way: extend of ArrayList or extend of AbstractList and how to forbid deleting (shadowing for example)?

Comment: Have you considered using [`Collections.unmodifiableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-)?

Comment: "Better way" is a very vague expression here? How do you measure the goodness of the solution?

Comment: Thanks everyone to answers, but I need only forbid deleting, so Collections.unmodifiableList does not fit because it does not allow to modify the data

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
public class NotRemovableArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: "The question is what is the better way: extend of ArrayList or extend of AbstractList". And this is not the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Common approach is to throw `UnsupportedOperationException`
in method's implementation. Throw this exception
from method that will not be used but
they are part of used public API.

If you want to totally implement all the methods
then you should use `List` interface.
Otherwise - use provided abstract variant or
directly extend from desired implementation
and override default behavior.

Comment: "The question is what is the better way: extend of ArrayList or extend of AbstractList"

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt and? second part of the answer is particular addressing that.